# weird Json deserialization on a read-only property in C#

Tags: c#, json, reflection, json.net

Can somebody explain how does it work? I even use reflection to set value to B, but it said B dont have a set value. How Newtonsoft.Json make this work?

```
public class A
{
    private int a = 10;
    public int B => a;
}

var a = new A();
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a);//json={"B":10}

//my expectation: this will have error, because B only have getter, dont have setter
//in reality: this run OK, and aa.B = aa.a = 10
var aa = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>(json);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not actually deserialising the B property. It's only "working" because by default `a == 10`. Take this code for example:

```
public class A
{
    private int a = 10;
    public int B => a;

    public A(){}

    public A(int a)
    {
        this.a = a;
    }
}

var a = new A(5);
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a); //json={"B":5}
var aa = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>(json);
Console.WriteLine(aa.B); // Prints 10.
```

Comment: so weird, it should throw an exception in this case